# Get full path for a file in python

Tags: python, csv, path, os.walk

I'm trying to create a csv of paths to wav files in a series of directories. Each row should correspond to a directory. Each cell in a row should contain the path to a single file. The script below is "almost" working. It creates a CSV with the files as cells. However, os.path.realpath and os.path.abspath don't include the direct parent directory of the file. So, instead of "/root/directory/file.wav". I'm getting "/root/file.wav".

```
import fnmatch
import os
import csv

with open('filelist.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    lister = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
      matches = []
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.wav'):
        matches.append(os.path.realpath(filename))
        if len(matches) > 0:
          print matches
          lister.writerow(matches)
```

Comment: As a side note, your mix of 1, 2, and 4 space indentation makes your code hard to read, and it would be even worse if your code weren't a perfect tree with no dedents. In fact, I think you _might_ actually have an indentation error in your code, but it's hard to be sure. Do you really want to write the first match, then the first two matches, then the first three, then the first four, etc.? Because that's what your code does. And that `if` statement is pointless if it comes after an `append`, because it will always be true.

Comment: Also, you don't need `os.walk(os.getcwd())`, just `os.walk('.')` is fine. And you don't need `if len(matches) > 0:`, just `it matches:`. (Most of this is in PEP 8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` the `root` path to get a relative path from the current directory, *then* you can call `abspath`.*

You can see this in every one of the examples for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) in the docs, like this one:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
```

---

So, for your code:

```
with open('filelist.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    lister = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        matches = []
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.wav'):
            matches.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)))
            if len(matches) > 0:
                print matches
                lister.writerow(matches)
```

---

<sub>* Alternatively, you can start the `walk` with an absolute path and not have to `abspath` each file… but only if you understand what that means for symlinks and are happy with that. If you don't know, use `abspath` on each file.</sub>

Comment: Yep. Yep. That did it. Out of curiosity, what if I just wanted the output of the parent directory and the file (excluding the root volume)?

Comment: @BaileySmith: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about removing the drive letter on Windows and getting an absolute-within-the-drive path starting with `\` instead of `D:\`? Or getting a path relative to the mount point on Unix? Or just a usable relative path (relative to the current directory) instead of an absolute path? Or …?